# About thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

We all know that energy of universe is constant but when it comes to reversible process,as per the definition it is said that the process which has initial and final state same and the process should not cause any change of energy to universe. 
But the energy of universe is constant ,the energy supplied by the reversible process must be acquired from the universe...

Comment: We certainly don't know that the energy of the universe is constant. We don't even know if it's even well defined.

Comment: Is the energy of universe not constant

Comment: @curiousone energy of universe is considered constant by convention.

Comment: @sai: you yourself said in your question about same initial and final state.So, whatever be the process, energy borrowed from surrounding is returned back to it.

Comment: @abhinav.so what is the difference between reversible and irreversible process

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: Physics is not driven by convention but by observation. Can you cite a paper detailing a precision measurement of the total energy of the universe?

Comment: the question seemed to be of class 11. all major books taught in school have clearly mentioned to consider energy of universe to be constant.

Comment: @sai: reversible process are in state of equilibrium in transition state. They move in forward or backward direction at any time. Activation energy is required to convert a reactant into product. In irreversible processes product formed has new properties which disable it from forming back reactant.

Comment: also when a body moves with constant velocity no work is done.

Comment: Then a process which has initial and final states as same but releases energy(heat has been released to universe)then what is it called(read my question Also)

Comment: if energy is released to surroundings it means energy has been absorbed by it in past which is now released.Such reactions are eothermic and not reversible without supplying energy. Reversible process can be reversed without supplying any energy.

Answer (score 0):

when a an object moves with constant velocity in an isolated system then no work is done.
Similarly
during a reversible process if we do a small work to give object/process a velocity/go then it moves in forward direction with no consumption of energy.

Comment: I question your first statement. For example, if you have a block on a floor moving at some velocity (friction exists), do you not need to do work on it to keep its velocity constant?

Comment: Yes we need to do work.For in that case velocity is actually reducing.

Comment: so, it means the object is deaccelerating . So we have to apply force on it means give it positive acceleration ,so that , its acceleration and deacceleration cacel out to give 0 velocity. it means work is being done.

Comment: Yes, so it would be wrong to give that as a generalized statement.

Comment: I edited it to say isolated system iin answer. thanks

Comment: OP neither accepted this nor upvoted . its bad.